# ANTLR4: Reusing rule alternative label for several alternatives causes rule elements to not appear in the context class

Tags: antlr4

I have an expression rule that looks like this:

```
expression : '(' expression ')'   # ParenthesizedExpression
       | literal                  # LiteralExpression
       | identifier               # IdentifierExpression
       | functionCall             # FunctionCallExpression
       | Minus expression         # UnaryNumericExpression
       | Not expression           # LogicalNotExpression
       | expression Caret<assoc=right> expression           # BinaryNumericExpression
       | expression (Times|DividedBy|ModuloDiv) expression  # BinaryNumericExpression
       | expression (Plus|Minus) expression                 # BinaryNumericExpression
       | expression '='<assoc=right> expression             # AssignmentExpression
       | expression PlusEquals<assoc=right> expression      # AssignmentExpression
       | expression MinusEquals<assoc=right> expression     # AssignmentExpression
       | expression TimesEquals<assoc=right> expression     # AssignmentExpression
       | expression DivdedByEquals<assoc=right> expression  # AssignmentExpression
       | expression ModuloEquals<assoc=right> expression    # AssignmentExpression
       ;
```

The rule labels for `BinaryNumericExpression` and `AssignmentExpression` create only one set of `enterXXX` and `exitXXX` methods for the listener, as expected.  However, the associated context classes that are generated (`AssignmentExpressionContext`, and `BinaryNumericExpressionContext`), only include methods for the rule components of the last instance of each respective label.  For example, the last usage of the `BinaryNumericExpression` label in my rule was for `expression (Plus|Minus) expression`. Therefore, the `BinaryNumericExpressionContext` class only has methods `Plus()` and `Minus()`. Conspicuously missing are `Caret()`, `Times()`, `DividedBy()`, and `ModuloDiv()`. An analogous scenario is found with the `AssignmentExpressionContext` class, only a `ModuloEquals()` method is found.

My questions are: 1) Is this a bug or "working as designed"? 2) Will I have to create a separate label for each of the rule alternatives in order to be able to examine which operator was matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. I wasn't aware that this was intended to be a supported case when I implemented the analysis algorithm for generating the context accessor methods. You should file a bug report on the project issue tracker.

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues